# How to Rotate Objects in The Sims 4

Tags: the-sims-4

I just bought The Sims 4 and so far it's great but I don't know how to rotate objects. How do you rotate items?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the keyboard keys (<kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd>), or you can right-click on the mouse.

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> buttons on keyboard will turn it either way you want it.